# Where can I obtain libnet.so's source code?

Tags: linux, networking, java

[`libnet.so`](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/libnet.so.1) is the system library that Java (linux distro) uses for all its native networking calls.  I'm trying to debug a complicated networking issue involving a Java app, and need to take a peek at some code inside this module.

But for the life of me, I can't find where the source code would be hosted. Not extremely concerned with the version here, so long as its a recent release. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which OS distribution are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are o.k. with using an rpm then you can grab the CentOS source rpm for openjdk from [here](http://vault.centos.org/6.4/os/Source/SPackages/).

**why openjdk:**

According to my workstation:

```
find /usr -name libnet.so
```

points me to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so, and

```
rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
```

returns java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-1.57.1.11.9.el6_4.x86_64

Comment: Thanks @gsiems (+1) - I appreciate the help but I don't think the RPM contains the actual source code - it just contains the binary.

Answer (score 2):

For RHEL6, the source RPM is located here: 
http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/26/dist/74/size/1192857/name/libnet-1.1.5-1.el6.src.rpm